# Is there another way to show data in DataGridView ?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I dont like the way the data is displayed in DataGridView.

That's how I usually display it :

```
SqlCmd GetCity = new SqlCmd();
CityDataGridView.DataSource = GetCity.UseSqlCommand("SELECT * FROM City").Tables[0];
```

SqlCmd is a class that I use to execute Sql queries or to return dataset.

I want the data to be displayed in the datagridview in a more elegant way. How can I do it?

Comment: So... what do you want to do?

Comment: there are many commertial products like:http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/sample-applications.aspx

Comment: I will serach  for ListView and see how its looks like , which one of them (Datagrid or listview ) is better ?

Wow Nahum , what is that  !? it look's so beautiful how i use that in my project ?

Comment: what is `more elegant` ? there are countless ways of customizing appearance of `DatagGridView` and if you don't need edit, then perhaps `ListView` in `View=Details` mode could be much easier to customize indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik and DevExpress have nice looking controls, but those are commercial (PAID) products. If you can't afford them, I strongly suggest you look at leaving winforms behind and use current UI technology (WPF).

winforms doesn't support customization, and native winforms controls look like windows 95.

You can get Professional-looking applications in WPF without paying any commercial third-parties. Just google WPF Application (in google images search) and see it for yourself.

Comment: I will make my future with WPF BUT , this is a school project and they say we must use windows forms for this project..

so there's any other idea you have to help me show data in datagridview ? (Im dont have to show it in other way i still can get A+ but i want to try :) )

Comment: @user2120874 that's why I abandoned university... they force you into dead dinosaur technologies which don't even make sense to learn.

Comment: yea I know but im still in high school so if I abandon my school i'll never get a job.. I think I just use the regular datagridview and get my A+

Just FYI , me and my friend are the only who make the project with VS2010 , the other make it with Visual Basic 06 . (yea i cant belive it too )